# A function return different object based on its parameter?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a bunch of  functions like this:

```
void Business::convertDataToListEntityOfTypeX() // X = A,B,C.....

{

    QByteArray tmp = getData();
    bool ok;
    QVariantList result = parse (tmp,&ok);

    if (ok) {

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
            TypeXEntity e;

            convertVariantToTypeXEntity(result[i],e);
            typeXEntityList.push_back(e);//typeXEntityList are private variables in Business
        }
    }


}
```

I want to group them into one function like this

```
enum Type{TypeA, TypeB};
void Business::convertDataToListEntity(Type tp)

{

    QByteArray tmp = getData();
    bool ok;
    QVariantList result = parse (tmp,&ok);

    if (ok) {

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
            TypeXEntity e;// need a magic function map the enum with TypeXEntity

            convertVariantToTypeXEntity(result[i],e);
            typeXEntityList.push_back(e);//need a magic function map the enum with TypeXEntityList
        }
    }


}
```

So is there any possible way to do this with `Qt` or `Boost` (Qt is prefered ) ?

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Comment: It's most likely possible, but to me it has kind of a bad design smell. Can't it be solved with inheritance and polymorphism? Or proxy objects of some kind? Templates?

Comment: Those "TypeX" class hold info of different entities which are nothing in common. In another way, we use those just to store data.

Comment: Sure you don't just want a template, and perhaps a dispatcher?

Comment: Yes, perhaps a dispatcher.

Comment: @Tiana987642: what exactly was wrong with QVariant(List)? I do not know why you would use dispatcher or template for such things, given that you want to do mapping.

Comment: Because I need `QList <typeX> typeXEntityList` to use as input of other function :(